# Can I buy the Samsung official extended battery for the UK Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: battery, samsung-galaxy-nexus

Samsung have released an [extended battery for the US Galaxy Nexus](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones-accessories/ETC-I515BBGSTA).  I know the US and EU versions have a slightly different shape, so was wondering if this extended battery would fit my UK Galaxy Nexus?  Or if there's a version which would fit?

Comment: Where did you read they have a different shape?

Comment: @shawn I think I've seen it on Droid-Life. For some reason, I don't think they are compatible

Comment: Oh! I now remember: the LTE version is already thick as it is because of the additional LTE antenna.  So putting a LTE battery in a non-LTE version might be too big. I can't confirm if it will work or not, so hence a comment instead of an answer

Comment: In the ad I saw for the extended battery it came with a new cover, so perhaps it would work anyways? I'd say just go for it, and post your experience as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Engadget has a great comparison shot of the battery differences between the HSPA+ and LTE versions in their [review of the Verizon (LTE) Galaxy Nexus](http://www.engadget.com/2011/12/16/verizon-galaxy-nexus-review/). The short answers seems to be 'no'; the link you provided is to an extended battery for the LTE Galaxy Nexus and therefore wouldn't be compatible with your HSPA+ version.